# Terminal always shows these extra lines after being opened

Tags: command-line, bash, kubuntu, konsole

I am using Kubuntu 22.04.3. Whenever I open the terminal (or konsole), the following five lines are always displayed.

```
bash: enable: bash: not a shell builtin
bash: enable: completion: not a shell builtin
bash: enable: in: not a shell builtin
bash: enable: interactive: not a shell builtin
bash: enable: shells: not a shell builtin
```

I am not sure what these lines mean. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please look for those terms in your startup files like `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile` and the like. Then edit your question and add any occurrences you've found. If I had to guess, I'd reckon that you copy-and-paste'd something into a startup file that contains a comment, and didn't copy the starting `#`. Something like `for bash completion in interactive shells` instead of `# for bash completion in interactive shells`. But without looking into your files, this is just guesswork.

Comment: FWIW `# enable bash completion in interactive shells` is a comment in the default `/etc/bash.bashrc` file - so I'd check there first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`enable`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-enable) is a Bash shell builtin command that takes/expects other shell builtin commands as arguments to list, enable or disable them ... You appear to have an uncommented statement/line like `enable bash completion in interactive shells` in one of the [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) and that shouldn't be there ... Those startup files are sourced automatically every time an interactive shell is started (*like when opening a new terminal ... mainly the files `~/.bashrc` and, on Ubuntu, `/etc/bash.bashrc` for interactive non-login shells ... As well as any other files that are sourced in those files with `. file` or `source file`*) and all lines in them are parsed and commands in them are executed in the current working shell unless a line is commented out by having `#` at its beginning ... Therefore, this might happen:

```bash
$ enable bash completion in interactive shells
bash: enable: bash: not a shell builtin
bash: enable: completion: not a shell builtin
bash: enable: in: not a shell builtin
bash: enable: interactive: not a shell builtin
bash: enable: shells: not a shell builtin
```

Comment: Many many thanks. This solves my issue.